# VBA Compile error syntax error what is wrong?

Tags: vba, syntax, compiler-errors

I have the following code and I keep getting errors on the same line. 
  With .Range("A18:bz18").AutoFilter Field:=78, Criteria1:=">14"

I have tried various things and I cannot get it right.  I'm very new to VBA and don't think I fully understand it yet, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim writeRow As Long

Sheets("master").UsedRange.Offset(1).ClearContents    

Application.ScreenUpdating = False    

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets    

    If ws.Name <> "master" And ws.Name <> "BAF_MASTER" And ws.Name <> "Lookup_Sheet" And ws.Name <> "Front_Sheet" And ws.Name <> "COMMITTEE_MENU" And ws.Name <> "EFFECTS_OF_CONTROL" And ws.Name <> "BAF_GUIDE" And ws.Name <> "Strategy_Guide" And ws.Name <> "Master_Template" Then    

        writeRow = Sheets("master").Cells(Rows.count, "y").End(xlUp).Row + 1    

        With ws    
                    .AutoFilterMode = False        

                        With .Range("A18:bz18").AutoFilter Field:=78, Criteria1:=">14"    

                          .Offset(1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("master").Range("A" & writeRow)    
                        End With     

                    .AutoFilterMode = False    
        End With    
    End If    

Next ws    


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim writeRow As Long

Sheets("master").UsedRange.Offset(1).ClearContents

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    If (ws.Name <> "master") And _
        (ws.Name <> "BAF_MASTER") And _
        (ws.Name <> "Lookup_Sheet") And _
        (ws.Name <> "Front_Sheet") And _
        (ws.Name <> "COMMITTEE_MENU") And _
        (ws.Name <> "EFFECTS_OF_CONTROL") And _
        (ws.Name <> "BAF_GUIDE") And _
        (ws.Name <> "Strategy_Guide") And _
        (ws.Name <> "Master_Template") Then
        writeRow = Sheets("master").Cells(Rows.Count, "y").End(xlUp).Row + 1

        With ws
            .AutoFilterMode = False
            With .Range("A18:bz18")
                .AutoFilter Field:=78, Criteria1:=">14"
                .Offset(1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("master").Range("A" & writeRow)
            End With
            .AutoFilterMode = False
        End With

    End If

Next ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Also is a good idea to separate your conditions in if statement.see code.

Comment: Thanks for this. Using this code I'm now getting an error run time 1004 autofilter method of range class failed on line     .AutoFilter Field:=78, Criteria1:=">14"  .Field 78  is a helper column that takes data using = cell from a calculated  column.   Thanks

Comment: yes column 78 is bz and the values are numbers.  The cell contains =BYrowumber (eg. BZ19 contains =BY19 showing the value) to give the value in the previous column which is calculated using an if statement.

Comment: please send more details like a an image of cell A18 & BZ18

Comment: Sorry Error 1004 - how do I do that?

Comment: Take some images with snip tool, edit your question,select the fifth tap on the tool bar above what you have write and select the images.

Comment: For some reason the files are not uploading.  Is there anything else I can do?  Thanks for all your help in this.  Row 18 is my header row for my table.

Comment: i think the code works fine.i just try it.don t upload file just take some pictures and upload them to check your sheet.

Comment: I can't upload them.  The add picture button is greyed out, and when I click on click here in the box; I can select the picture to insert but nothing happens.  Do you think it's something with one of my other sheets?